# select rows from a DataFrame based on column value, limit to 16384 rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a huge *.csv file contains data as the example below, and had load the *.csvfile to a dataframe named as "data"

[image]

I want to select the rows that with "CHR" column equals to "1", and my code is as below

```
selected_row = data.loc[data['CHR'] == '1']
```

the result of selected_row is correct(row 0/3/6/7/10/13 are selected in the example), however, not containing all the rows with column equals to "1", I finally found selected_row contains rows with CHR=='1' till the 16384 row of data, the 16385 row (and many following rows) of data with CHR=='1' is not selected in selected_row, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
selected_row = data.loc[data['CHR'].isin([1, '1'])]
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the 'CHR' column means chromosome and valid values are '1','2','3'....'22','X' and 'Y', so I treated this column as character, not integer, any suggestion ?

Comment: thanks. By the way, it is strange that if I specify data type when reading the *.csv file, the problem also disappeared, not really know the reason behind and just for anyone's reference


data = pandas.read_csv("mydata.csv",dtype={"CHR":"string"})

Answer (score 0):

i think you have got your filters mixed up
to make it more easier for you
Now apply the filter to your dataframe
#try this

````
filter_row= data['CHR'] == '1']. #this would return a dataframe with boolean values which you can then use afterwards


```
data.loc[filter_row]
````

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone.
By the way, it is strange that if I specify data type when reading the *.csv file, the problem also disappeared, not really know the reason behind and just for anyone's reference

```
data = pandas.read_csv("mydata.csv",dtype={"CHR":"string"})
```